# Primefaces, autocomplete and accessibility

Tags: jsf-2, autocomplete, primefaces, accessibility

Well, after some trials with ICEFaces and after the suggestion of @BalusC I decide to try PrimeFaces.
The first thing I would add to my project (simple JSF2 and JPA2) is the AutoComplete component.
I'm blind so after some trials I asked to a my collegue to see the page and she told me that the autocomplete worked properly!
Now my question is: is possible modify the p:autoComplete style to  seems a simple combo box or something more accessible?

P.S.: I found this component:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf
but I don't understand if the section editable works like autoComplete or is used to add a new option...

[EDIT:]
After some trials I can tell you that:
1) if I try p:autoComplete the screen reader doesn't read the suggestions;
2) If I try the p:selectOneMenu I can't edit the select but I can navigate into the combo box...
Thank you for your help!

Comment: The example in the showcase doesn't work like autocomplete rather like adding a new option.

Comment: @Matt : ok thanks Mat! One doubt is resolved!

Comment: @Filippo1980 I am sure that the folks at Primefaces are concerned about accessibility issues as are most application developers.  Please feel free to submit issues to the [Primefaces Issue List](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list) so that they are aware of this and can potentially address this concern in a future release.

Comment: Regarding PrimeFaces and accessibility, please see [link](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1618 "this page"). Accessibility has been decided to be improved iteratively with each PrimeFaces release. For the components that you'd like see more accessibility features, please create an enhancement request in PF issue tracker.

Comment: @Maple_Shaft : thank you for your comment but I don't know if it is an issue or, simple, an option that I can change from CSS...

Comment: @Cagatay_Civici : thank you for the link, I'm happy that soon PrimeFaces will be more accessible but I don't understand a thing: for now I can't change anything to use the autoComplete tag or you just say that in the next versions this issue will not appear without "strange setup"?

Comment: SelectOneMenu doesn't support autoComplete suggestions with ajax but it supports editing if editable option is set true. In future, autoComplete suggestions will be screen readable for sure. I'm not sure what you meant by strange setup.

Comment: @Cagatay_Civici : sorry for that phrase but I would say only a custom setup on CSS...